# Images don't show up on AWS Amplify but works fine in development mode

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, next-auth

I have deployed my Next.js project on AWS Amplify, and while images are loading fine in `development mode`, they are not loading in `production mode`. I have tried several things, including:

Selecting the "**Legacy cache settings**" option and changing the "**Query strings**" field to "**all**" in CloudFront's "**Cache key and origin requests**" section.
Updating the "Source address" field to "/<*>", and the "Type" field to "404 (rewrite)" in Amplify's "**App settings** > **Rewrites and redirects**" section.
Directly importing the images as strings from **Cloudinary** and `S3`.
I have been struggling with this issue for hours, and none of the solutions I have tried so far have worked. Any help would be wholeheartedly appreciated.Endlesss thanks to you all

here is my app:
https://main.d2ip8v7kintl3l.amplifyapp.com/

Comment: DNS Record not found for main.d2ip8v7kintl3l.amplifyapp.com.

Comment: @jarmod yeah, just switched to netlify, but now getting another issue, receiving 502 error when trying to navigate to signin page, though works perfectly in localhost, posted the topic everywhere i can..but no luck...

https://musical-lokum-78f90a.netlify.app/

Comment: Wow no answer for this issue, it does not surprise me, because there are so many issues in this community most are not being solved.

Comment: Idk, I gave up on Amplify lol. We have a VPS now. Serverless sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Need to set:

```js
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
```

in your `next.config.js`. AWS doesn't support image optimization by default.

Comment: AWS docs say it does...but it seems like "Sharp" needs to be installed whatever that means...?
But in version beyond Next.js 13.4.11 Images definitely seems broken.
I cannot confirm optimization because I do not know what I am looking for. - - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/ssr-Amplify-support.html

Comment: I abandoned Amplify, but I think you were correct.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the missing image suffix types in my redirect rules in the AWS Amplify console. I had changed my images from PNG and JPEG to use AVIF and WEBP but didn't add a redirect rule. When I did add that rule, as seen below, images started working again.

[image: aws console]